# NServiceBus - replying to message after publish

Tags: c#, nservicebus

I have a subscriber that successfully handles a message, the subscriber then proceeds to successfully publish another message to state that a certain event has happened, my problem is that i after the publish i attempt to return a message to the sender of the initial message and the system fails with the following message

> No destination specified for message NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.CompletionMessage. Message cannot be sent. Check the UnicastBusConfig section in your config file and ensure that a MessageEndpointMapping exists for the message type.

The return code looks as follows:

```
 Bus.Publish(orderMessage);

 Bus.Return((int)MySendBus.Core.ErrorCode.Ok);
```

and the app.config is as follows:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="MsmqTransportConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.MsmqTransportConfig, NServiceBus.Core"/>
  </configSections>

  <MsmqTransportConfig InputQueue="MyServerInputQueue" ErrorQueue="error" NumberOfWorkerThreads="1" MaxRetries="5"/>
</configuration>
```

I've added a unicast section and still get the same error. My understanding is that NServicebus knows how to reply to the message and i shouldn't have to specify a queue for the reply to go on other than the MsmqTransportConfig input queue found in the app.config.

Is it possible to have a subscriber publish a message then respond to the where the message was sent?

Comment: Can you post your Unicast section?  I've had success with using Bus.Reply(), would that work for you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use Bus.Return() then you must register a call back on the client endpoint like so:

```
Bus.Send<IRequestDataMessage>(m =>
            {
                m.DataId = g;
                m.String = "<node>it's my \"node\" & i like it<node>";
            })
                .Register(i => Console.Out.WriteLine(
                                   "Response with header 'Test' = {0}, 1 = {1}, 2 = {2}.",
                                   Bus.CurrentMessageContext.Headers["Test"],
                                   Bus.CurrentMessageContext.Headers["1"],
                                   Bus.CurrentMessageContext.Headers["2"]));
```

If you want to return a full message of your choosing then use Bus.Reply() and write a handler in your client endpoint.  My full sample can be found [here](https://github.com/afyles/Blog/tree/master/NServiceBusExplorer/Source/RequestResponse).

Comment: Thank you Adam. You're sample has helped me in the right direction.

Using your samples I realised i was missing a MsmqTransportConfig in the sender of the initial message. This fixed the problem.